# Angular 2 binding ngIf programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a page header component which has two states:

- Standard: Shows detailed content
- Compacted: Shows minimal content

The idea is that this component can be added to any 'page' component like so:

**home.component.html**

```
<app-page-header>

    <app-page-header-standard>
        // Standard Content
    </app-page-header-standard>

    <app-page-header-compact>
        // Compact Content
    </app-page-header-compact>

</app-page-header>
```

The code I have so far:

**page-header.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- The standard and compact components are transcluded here -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <a (click)="toggleHeaderState()">Toggle me</a>
</div>
```

**page-header.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input, ContentChild} from '@angular/core';
import {PageHeaderStandardComponent} from "./page-header-standard.component";
import {PageHeaderCompactComponent} from "./page-header-compact.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-header',
    templateUrl: './page-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page-header.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @ContentChild(PageHeaderStandardComponent) headerStandard: PageHeaderStandardComponent;
    @ContentChild(PageHeaderCompactComponent) headerCompact: PageHeaderCompactComponent;

    /**
     * Toggle the header standard and compact state
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    @Input() compacted: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.headerStandard);
        console.log(this.headerCompact);

        // TODO
        // Bind compact and standard component to compacted input
        // i.e. one hides while the other shows
    }

    toggleHeaderState() {
        this.compacted = !this.compacted;
    }
}
```

**The Question:**
How do I assign an ngIf to the two ContentChild components in the ngOnInit function? i.e. show one component when the `compacted` input is true and then show the other when the `compacted` input is false

Comment: What about using ngIf directly in the template? Why in ngoninit???

Comment: The page-header-standard and page-header-compact components are not nested inside the page-header component. They are transcluded inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in the end by using a template loader directive.

The template loader directive allows the user to optionally include either the header compact and header standard templates. If either template is not included it is hidden and no empty divs or containers are left in the markup.

The resulting (simplified) markup looks like:

**app.component.html**

```
<wbo-page-header>
    <template pageHeaderStandardTemplate>
        // Standard Content
    </template>

    <template pageHeaderCompactTemplate>
        // Compact Content
    </template>
</wbo-page-header>
```

**page-header.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header-standard" *ngIf="pageHeaderStandardTemplate && !compacted" >
        <template [templateLoader]="pageHeaderStandardTemplate"></template>
    </div>

    <div class="header-compact" *ngIf="pageHeaderCompactTemplate && compacted">
        <template [templateLoader]="pageHeaderCompactTemplate"></template>
    </div>

    <span ngIf*="pageHeaderStandardTemplate && pageHeaderCompactTemplate" (click)="toggleCompactedState">Toggle Header</span>
</div>
```

**page-header.component.ts**

```
/**
 * Directive to define a template for the page header standard
 */
@Directive({selector: '[pageHeaderStandardTemplate]'})
export class PageHeaderStandardTemplate {
}

/**
 * Directive to define a template for the page header compact
 */
@Directive({selector: '[pageHeaderCompactTemplate]'})
export class PageHeaderCompactTemplate {
}


@Component({
    // Removed for simplicity
})
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() compacted: boolean = false;

    /**
     * Define the Page Header Standard template
     */
    @ContentChild(PageHeaderStandardTemplate, {read: TemplateRef}) public pageHeaderStandardTemplate;

    /**
     * Define the Page Header Standard template
     */
    @ContentChild(PageHeaderCompactTemplate, {read: TemplateRef}) public pageHeaderCompactTemplate;

    /**
     * Toggle the header compacted state
     */
    toggleCompactedState() {
        this.compacted = !this.compacted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically add `ngIf`. You can set the `hidden` attribute

```ts
@ContentChild(PageHeaderStandardComponent, {read: ElementRef}) headerStandard: PageHeaderStandardComponent;
@ContentChild(PageHeaderCompactComponent, {read: ElementRef}) headerCompact: PageHeaderCompactComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.headerStandard);
    console.log(this.headerCompact);
    this.headerStandard.nativeElement.setAttribute('hidden', !compacted);
    this.headerCompact.nativeElement.setAttribute('hidden', compacted);
}
```

Comment: This still leaves the element in the DOM and just hides it with `display: none`

Comment: That's right, but as I said, there is no way to add `ngIf` dynamically. You can also remove the element if you don't need to re-add it later instead of setting `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

If the header will only have standard/compact components you could project them like this and use `*ngIf` directly in that template

For **page-header.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ng-content select="app-page-header-standard" *ngIf="!compacted"></ng-content>

    <ng-content select="app-page-header-compact" *ngIf="compacted"></ng-content>

    <a (click)="toggleHeaderState()">Toggle me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That was an original implementation but raised problems with the elements needing to be wrapped. You end up with a container div for each that may or may not have content.

Comment: You mean you end up with an empty `<div class="wrapper" .. ` ?

Comment: The compact and standard header are styled differently. This means both the ng-content elements have to be wrapped in a div with a unique class i.e. `<div class="header-standard"><ng-content select="....` to enable specific styling. If no content is added there will be an empty div.

Comment: Could you not then just attach the `*ngIf` to the div rather than the `ng-content` element so you get all or nothing?