# Adding *ngIf to a generated ng2 component after page load

Tags: javascript, angular

I am  trying to add an *ngIf=booleanValue statement to all columns in ng2-smart-table.  I currently have retrieved the component with

```
@ViewChild('ng2Smart') test: ElementRef;
```

and when I do

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.test);
}
```

it returns

```
Ng2SmartTableComponent {settings: {…}, rowSelect: EventEmitter, userRowSelect: EventEmitter, delete: EventEmitter, edit: EventEmitter, …}
create
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
createConfirm
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
custom
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
defaultSettings
:
{mode: "inline", selectMode: "single", hideHeader: false, hideSubHeader: false, actions: {…}, …}
delete
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
deleteConfirm
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
edit
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
editConfirm
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
grid
:
Grid {createFormShown: false, onSelectRowSource: Subject, settings: {…}, dataSet: DataSet, source: ServerDataSource}
isAllSelected
:
false
isHideHeader
:
false
isHideSubHeader
:
false
isPagerDisplay
:
true
perPageSelect
:
{display: true, perPage: 20}
rowClassFunction
:
ƒ ()
rowHover
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
rowSelect
:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
settings
:
{pager: {…}, actions: {…}, columns: {…}}
source
:
ServerDataSource {onChangedSource: Subject, onAddedSource: Subject, onUpdatedSource: Subject, onRemovedSource: Subject, data: Array(20), …}
tableClass
:
""
tableId
:
""
```

which is exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm not sure of the best method to add the ngIf statement from here though.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: `*ngIf` is usually applied in the template code. Why not going that way? Could you share your `*.component.html`?

Comment: Away from my computer right now. I would like to not alter the source code of ng2 smart table because when I launch the app in production mode it won't allow edited node modules

Comment: You can not do that actually. Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712551/482868

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 binding ngIf programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712313/angular-2-binding-ngif-programmatically)